# Praxis Works M30 crankset to FSA BB30 fitted in a BB386EVO shell

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, axle, bb30

I have a BB386EVO frame shell and a FSA PF BB30 fitted into it. All good with this

Now, I have a Praxis Works M30 crankset that I want to use but I haven't been able to install. The axle seems too long with only the bearing cover and washer. I have tried a FSA BB386-30 adaptors but it do not seem to work... Not sure if I am missing something?

Any advice will be much appreciated

Comment: Do you mean *Praxis*? What BB standard are the new cranks for?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean Praxis Works. ... And that is the problem, I don't really know, crank axle is 30mm dia. and has 28mm ending on the non-driver side. It is an older model of this one https://praxiscycles.com/product/alba-m30/

Comment: I'd measure the part of the spindle that sits in the BB and compare against a list of BB standards https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/buyers-guides/the-complete-guide-to-bottom-bracket-standards/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Praxis web site it looks like M30 is a proprietary BB and you need a specific Praxis M30 to BB386 adapter.

Strange that you tried PF30 BB units in a BB386, but I think maybe the cups and bearings are the same. According to https://www.bikeradar.com/advice/buyers-guides/the-complete-guide-to-bottom-bracket-standards/ they both use 6806 bearings and a frame shell diameter of 46mm.

Comment: I think now that I have is  386EVO BB that has the same 6806 bearings (I was wrong). However I reckon now that the BB and the cranks are not compatible. the reason is that the M30 has a 28mm dia. end on the non-driver side. (see https://wheelsmfg.com/crankset-tech) making it non suitable for the the current 30mm bearing. mmmmmm puzzled and sad :(

Comment: Just to add a bit of clarity: many cranks have axles that are uniformly 30mm in diameter. Praxis cranks have axles that are 30mm, tapering to 28mm on one side. Thus the need for a proprietary BB.